# Processing JSON data to use in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, type-conversion, external

I want to make charts from an external source of data using highcharts. The problem that I encountered is that I have incompatible data:

```
{
"channel":{
"id":1123376,
"name":"Global Weather Experiment Raspberry Pi",
"latitude":"0.0",
"longitude":"0.0",

"field1":"Temperature",
"field2":"Presurre",
"field3":"Humidity",
"field4":"Air Quality",
"field5":"Rain",
"field6":"Wind Speed",
"field7":"Wind Direction",
"field8":"Wind Power",

"created_at":"2016-10-22T11:37:27Z",
"updated_at":"2017-06-11T10:01:02Z",
"last_entry_id":5438},

"feeds":[
    {
    "created_at":"2017-06-11T09:01:02Z",
    "entry_id":5437,
    "field1":"23.13"
    },
    {
    "created_at":"2017-06-11T10:01:02Z",
    "entry_id":5438,
    "field1":"23.88"
    }
]}
```

I need to convert "created_at" and "field1" to make it look like this:

```
?([
    [Date.UTC(2017,6,11,09,01,02Z),23.13],
    [Date.UTC(2017,6,11,10,01,02Z),23.88]
]);
```

Of corse there are more entries, I need help with creating loop which can convert it, especially date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data={
"channel":{
"id":1123376,
"name":"Global Weather Experiment Raspberry Pi",
"latitude":"0.0",
"longitude":"0.0",

"field1":"Temperature",
"field2":"Presurre",
"field3":"Humidity",
"field4":"Air Quality",
"field5":"Rain",
"field6":"Wind Speed",
"field7":"Wind Direction",
"field8":"Wind Power",

"created_at":"2016-10-22T11:37:27Z",
"updated_at":"2017-06-11T10:01:02Z",
"last_entry_id":5438},

"feeds":[
    {
    "created_at":"2017-06-11T09:01:02Z",
    "entry_id":5437,
    "field1":"23.13"
    },
    {
    "created_at":"2017-06-11T10:01:02Z",
    "entry_id":5438,
    "field1":"23.88"
    }
]}
//console.log(data.feeds)
var rqData=data.feeds;
var formattedData=[]
for(var i=0;i<rqData.length;i++){
//formattedData array contains (fist data) date in milliseconds and (second data) in number 
 formattedData.push([Date.parse(rqData[i].created_at),Number(rqData[i].field1)])
}
//console.log(formattedData)


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Some Year',
        // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
        // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
        // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
        data: formattedData
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Pass `formattedData` in highcharts as

```
series: [{
    name: 'Some Year'
    data: formattedData
}]
```

and also `xAxis` contains `type: 'datetime',`

Comment: if you want to use `UTC` you can use [UTC setting](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really kind of you that you found some time to help me.